# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'items')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, ejs

Error:  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'items')
at C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\Web Development\todolist\app.js:105:17

> getting the error in the 1st app.post method -> else statement. stuck at it for almost a day.
> ps: code might not run as db link is changed by me

```
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const _ = require("lodash");
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(express.static("public"));
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://adminshivam:refd3sfde@cluster0.3igye.mongodb.net/todolistDB");


    
    const itemsSchema = { 
      name: String
    };
    
    const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);
    
    
    const item1 = new Item({
      name: "Welcome to your todolist!"
    });
    
    const item2 = new Item({
      name: "Hit the + button to add a new item."
    });
    
    const item3 = new Item({
      name: "<-- Hit this to delete an item."
    });
    
    const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];
    
    const listSchema = {
      name: String,
      items: [itemsSchema]
    };
    
    const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);
    
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    
      Item.find({}, function(err, foundItems){
    
        if (foundItems.length === 0) {
          Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log("Successfully savevd default items to DB.");
            }
          });
          res.redirect("/");
        } else {
          res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});
        }
      });
    
    });
    
    app.get("/:customListName", function(req, res){
      const customListName = _.capitalize(req.params.customListName);
    
      List.findOne({name: customListName}, function(err, foundList){
        if (!err){
          if (!foundList){
            //Create a new list
            const list = new List({
              name: customListName,
              items: defaultItems
            });
            list.save();
            res.redirect("/" + customListName);
          } else {
            //Show an existing list
    
            res.render("list", {listTitle: foundList.name, newListItems: foundList.items});
          }
        }
      });
    
    
    
    });
    
    app.post("/", function(req, res){
    
      const itemName = req.body.newItem;
      const listName = req.body.list;
    
      const item = new Item({
        name: itemName
      });
    
      if (listName === "Today"){
        item.save();
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        List.findOne({name: listName}, function(err, foundList){
          foundList.items.push(item);
          foundList.save();
          res.redirect("/" + listName);
        });
      }
    });
    
    app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
      const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
      const listName = req.body.listName;
    
      if (listName === "Today") {
        Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err){
          if (!err) {
            console.log("Successfully deleted checked item.");
            res.redirect("/");
          }
        });
      } else {
        List.findOneAndUpdate({name: listName}, {$pull: {items: {_id: checkedItemId}}}, function(err, foundList){
          if (!err){
            res.redirect("/" + listName);
          }
        });
      }
    
    
    });
    
    app.get("/about", function(req, res){
      res.render("about");
    });
    
    app.listen(3000, function() {
      console.log("Server started on port 3000");
    });
```

> error link from above code
> `foundList.items.push(item);`

> list.ejs

```
    <%- include("header") -%>
    
      <div class="box" id="heading">
        <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
      </div>
    
      <div class="box">
        <% newListItems.forEach((listItem) => { %>
          <form action="/delete" method="post">
            <div class="item">
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= listItem._id %>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
              <p><%=  listItem.name  %></p>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="listName" value="<%= listTitle %>"></input>
          </form>
          <% });%>
    
          <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
            <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %> ">+</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    
    <%- include("footer") -%>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem seems to be at your schema, you are not making it the right way, instead of passing an object to `moongose.model` like this:

```
const itemsSchema = { 
  name: String
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);
```

You should create a schema with the class `Schema` from mongoose, so try the following:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose

const itemsSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true}
})

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema)
```

And in your `listSchema` do the following:

```
const listSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  // define an array of id that references the Item schema
  items: [{type: ObjectId, ref: "Item", required: true, default: [] }]
});

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);

// the object named as list1 will contain a reference to id of  item1, item2 and item3.

const list1 = new List({name: "list1", items: [item1._id, item2._id, item3._id]}).save()
```

Further up, in your `post api` :

```
app.post("/", async function(req, res){

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;
  try {
    const item = new Item({ name: itemName });

    if (listName === "Today") {
      await item.save();
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      // save the item id to items field from list schema
      const list = await List.findOne({ name: listName })
      list.items.push(item._id)
      await list.save()

      // don't make a redirect within the database query
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    }
  } catch(err) {
    // If some error was threw handle it here
    // you can handle mongoose errors as follow:
    if(err instanceof mongoose.Error) {
      // use a custom message or err.message
      res.status(500).json({message: "error with Db"})
    }
    res.status(500).json({message: "something went wrong"})
  }
});
```

See [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition) to know more about it, as you are using references between your schemas I suggest you to take a look at the [populate method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate) because probably you will need it in the future. See the available [queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) from mongoose as well, almost everything you need is at the docs. Hope I helped you!

Comment: I tried your solution but still getting the same error, console keeps referring to items null at line 105 in app.js i.e          foundList.items.push(item);

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that you are making the listSchema as same way as itemsSchema, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @YagoBiermann and you don't need exec() after findOne ,
findOne unlike find() dose not return cursor instead it return an object

Comment: Thanks @YagoBiermann issue resolved using the above solution

Comment: so after removing default item how do you intend to replace the consequential parts of the code that have the default item in place after all that is the name of the array... your code does not make sense please... with all due respect try to make sense of your solution so we can understand @YagoBiermann

Comment: Sorry about that, just desconsider the comment to remove const defaultItem.

Answer (score -1):

just remove the space in ejs file

```
<button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
```